# vs2010 express asp.net c#: facebook beginner's application

Tags: asp.net, facebook

I followed all the instructions in the following links yet I am getting the following error

> Errors while loading page from application
>   The URL http://zsswfacebooklocal.com:1940/Default.aspx/ did not respond.

Has any one successfully got a simple asp.net application tested on facebook from their localhost on local dev machine. I did update my host file to have local ip 127.0.0.0 point to a temp domain name like zsswfacebooklocal.com

I used the following tutorials but no luck so far. Please help. For FB asp.net application: http://fbtutorial.qsh.eu/section1/step1.aspx

For local host: http://www.stevetrefethen.com/wiki/Facebook%20application%20development%20in%20ASP.NET.ashx

Answer (score 0):

The HOSTS workaround will only work if your app's render method set to IFrame, so double-check that.

On the other hand, if you require your render method to be FBML, then see my response in your other (similar) question:

[vs2010 express asp.net c#: facebook asp.net application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996676/vs2010-express-asp-net-c-facebook-asp-net-application)

If your app's render method is FBML, Facebook tries to load your website the same way anyone over the internet would, so you'd need to set your local website to be accessible to the internet.